# What are the options to add a full automatic underline in Libre office writer?

Tags: libreoffice

In Ubuntu 16.04 I edit a document with Libre Office Writer.

In my document I have an heading and some text. Consider:

```
Heading 1:

Some text...
```

I want to reach a state when it looks something like this:

```
Heading 1:____________________________________________

Some text...
```

### Desired solution features:

- The line should take full width of one row (from it's starting point).
- I need a way to edit the graphics of the line (change it's color, stroke, etc).

### Seemingly inefficient solutions:

- Using the regular underline (`U`) isn't automatic and can brake down in some narrow displays. I should note that if there is a clear distinction between `U` and `border-bottom` (as there is in HTML-CSS, a border-bottom solution might be good).
- Using a drawed line is also inautomatic, and has a quite of a chance of being asymetrical.

Comment: Where should the line start? After the colon, or at the beginning of the line?

Comment: The line should start after the colon...

Comment: This makes things difficult. You can add a line there (manually), but AFAIK you can't modify its style automatically. Applying a styled border at the bottom of the complete line would be much easier, but this doesn't fit your needs...

Comment: If the regular `U` and a styled border-bottom are different in LOW (as they are in HTML-CSS), then it might indeed fit my needs. I actually encourage you to publish an answer with any relevant tip you have on how to style the border. I will give bounty if needed @tohuwawohu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except the starting position of the line, adding a border at the bottom would be the best solution. You can achieve this the following way:

1. Open the Styles and formatting dialogue (hit <kbd>F11</kbd>, or select Menu View -> Styles and Formatting);
2. Select the "Heading 1" style (single left click);
3. Right-click to open context menu, select "Modify";
4. Select the "Borders" tab;
5. Add a bottom border, by clicking just below the gray rectangle in the "User defined" field at the left;
6. Set line style, line width, and color as desired;
7. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>;
8. Repeat 2-7 for other Heading styles, if required.

[image: Border properties of paragraph style]

That's it - now, every paragraph with "Heading 1" style should have a line at the bottom, with the desired color and so on.

As already pointed out in my comment, the border will always start **at the beginning of the line**. But since the line hase some small distance to the heading, any underlining will still be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method for page-width line starting after text, especially if your headings are different lengths of text (e.g. Heading1; Hding2; Heading Three):

1. Set the *Heading Style* to include a Tab stop (Right Justified) at the RHS of the document page.
2. Type heading text followed by tab space.
3. Underline the tab space.

LOwriter has some functionality for changing colour and stroke of underline (in the *Character* dialogue box) but is still a bit restricted.